# Can you manually handle specific API routes in Firebase database?

Tags: rest, api, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase as a RESTful API, but I would like to create some endpoints that will return specific statistics about the data in the db to the user. For example, how many registered users in the system are from a certain country. Is that possible in Firebase or do I have to make my own custom backend to handle the generation of those statistics based on the data already stored in the Firebase database?

Comment: Sure. Just run a server where you use one of our [server-side SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) to listen to the database and write your statistics.